# How can I get rid of us008n.dll symbol loading on debug-startup VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols

Recently, and I do not know exactly what might have changed, I'm seeing the following on starting a Debug-session on my project directly from VS2015:

> `Loading symbols for us008n.dll from \\107.109.101.32\common\users\Geeta\autoconfig\11-11\V2\GetSNMP\release\x64`
>
> [image: Debug Symbol loading]

Now, my project doesn't use this DLL 
(Apparently it is some spooler-dll found on my drive at `C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\x64\3`)
and I don't have a clue why VS attempts to load it's debugging symbols and where the IP address for it is coming from.

I've certainly checked that my Debug options do not load symbols:
[image: VS2015 Symbol-loading settings]

**Edit:**

> I also do not have a environmental variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` set.

Thanks [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for your comment.

### What have I missed?

Comment: The symbol server can also be specified by an environment variable.  Type `set | more` at the command prompt, look for `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion. I've now checked but no such varible is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Two, actually.

> ### Solution 1
>
> Make sure to uncheck the "Always load symbols located next to modules" option, if you're using "Only specified modules" as general strategy:
>
> [image: Solution 1]

---

> ### Solution 2
>
> Specify to *not* load the particular module, if you're using "All modules, unless excluded" as general strategy:
>
> [image]